# Visual basic radio buttons

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, radio-button

I have a program with radio buttons that are on a second form. When one of the radio buttons become checked it is to close that form. However, the first radio button is for some reason becoming checked causing the form to close. They are all set to be false on their checked property and their index order is 1-4. I set a label as index 0. I even set them false diagrammatically in the forms onload function, but the first radio button is still becoming checked. Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Show us the code where you're closing the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change them to check boxes; a radio button group always has a selection.

Comment: You are correct. I fixed the issue by setting one of their properties to checked because when the form loaded it was automatically checking one causing my function to execute.

Comment: better still have an "OK" button and put your code behind that. that would be better practice.

Answer (score 4):

just change the tabstop property to false.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make much sense to have a radio button close a form, since that isn't showing a selection, but acting on one.  Try changing them to Buttons.

If you have to have RadioButtons, try adding another focusable control, such as a Button, to be TabIndex=0 while the RadioButtons have TabIndexes > 0.  It's just the way it works.

The other alternative is to uncheck them in the `Shown` event:

```
Private Sub Form1_Shown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
  RadioButton1.Checked = False
  RadioButton2.Checked = False
  '// etc
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do what I just did, and create an extra (invisible) radio button on your form, and set that one to be checked=true. The others will then all be checked=false.

Simple.